# Managing memory in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Suppose I ensure that properties are deleted and objects are set to null after use in JavaScript prpgram.

1) Will this help me in better memory management? How do I verify this?

2) As far as I know, after deletion object representation will be changed to dictionary. Will this affect the overall performance?

Answer (score 0):

> Will this help me in better memory management?

Unlikely. Usually the objects go out of scope on their own anyway, and setting the variables holding them to `null` is just unnecessary - if not even slowing down the execution.

> How do I verify this?

Profile the memory consumption of your application with and without those lines.

> As far as I know, after deletion object representation will be changed to dictionary. Will this affect the overall performance?

Yes it will, adversely, so *don't do this*. Instead of `delete`ing properties, you should just set them to `null` via assignment, if you really care about destroying the reference.

But seriously, there is in general absolutely no need to "manage memory in javascript". The garbage collector works quite fine, and there's very rarely a need to help it. Unless you are programming in odd ways or doing terrible (or very advanced and critical) stuff, don't worry.